# matlab plot graph of data over an image

Tags: image, matlab, plot

What I would like to do is plot an image of a graph (from say a pdf file or a scanned image).  Next, I would like to overlay an axis on the graph in the image, and then plot data on that axis (over the image).

Using imtool, I know the coordinates of the graph in the image (x range = ~52-355 pixels, and y range = 23(top) -  262(bottom) pixels in this case).

This is what I have tried:

```
I = imread('C:\MATLAB\R2014a\help\images\ref\ftrans2_fig.png');
I = squeeze(uint8(mean(I,3)));
figure, imshow(I)
[rows, cols] = size(I);
x_data = (-1 : .01 : +1)';
y_data = 1 - x_data.^2;
h1 = axes('Position',([52, 23, 355-52, 262-23] ./ [cols, rows, cols, rows] ));
set(h1, 'Color', 'none')
hold on
plot(x_data, y_data, '-rx')
```

Question:  Knowing the pixel coordinates of the graph in the image, how do I determine the proper position of the axis in the figure, (my code fails to account for the actual size of the figure box, the gray border around the image).  I have to do this for several images and sets of data, so I would like an automated method, assuming I find the coordinates of the graphs in the image ahead of time.

Thanks for your reply!  (1st time posting, please be kind)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to solve your problem by forcing the image onto the same axis as the plot. Try this:

```
I = imread('C:\MATLAB\R2014a\help\images\ref\ftrans2_fig.png');
I = squeeze(uint8(mean(I,3)));
[rows, cols] = size(I);
x_data = (-1 : .01 : +1)';
y_data = 1 - x_data.^2;
h1 = axes('Position',([52, 23, 355-52, 262-23] ./ [cols, rows, cols, rows] ));
set(h1, 'Color', 'none')
hold on
image(I, 'Parent', h1);
plot(h1, x_data, y_data, '-rx')
```

That should at ensure that the plot axis and the image axis have the same origin, as they will be one and the same. You may need to adjust your sizing code. Let me know if that doesn't do it for you.

Good Luck!

Comment: This did not work.  If you have access to ftrans2_fig.png (ships with matlab) you will see that it made it very large, and plotted the data in just the corner.  Also, image produces a very ugly plot compared to imshow for some reason (a whole other issue).  But, thank you very much for the reply.

Comment: As I mentioned, you may have to adjust your sizing code, try manipulating the scale a bit more, as generally, the code above should solve the problem you asked about. (That the plot & image must always share an origin.) Try ensuring that the plot has the same max as the number of pixels in the image. You can't just overlay them and ensure that they will always overlap. You have to actually work with x_data and y_data to make them fit the size of the image. I'll look at this tomorrow, when I'm near my MATLAB machine...

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it figured out.
It would have been easier if I could use:

```
figure, h1=imshow(I)
get(h1,'Position')
```

but that results in "The name 'Position' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'image'."

Instead, this appears to work:

```
I = imread('C:\MATLAB\R2014a\help\images\ref\ftrans2_fig.png');
I = squeeze(uint8(mean(I,3)));
in_mag = 300;
figure, imshow(I, 'Border', 'tight', 'InitialMagnification', in_mag)
[rows, cols] = size(I);
x_data = (-1 : .01 : +1)';
y_data = 1 - x_data.^2;
% Coord of graph in image pixels
x_0 = 50; x_max = 354; y_0 = 262; y_max = 23;
h1 = axes('Position',([x_0,   rows-y_0,   x_max-x_0,   y_0-y_max] ...
                   ./ [cols,   rows,      cols,          rows] ));
set(h1,'Color','none')
hold on
plot(x_data, y_data, '-rx')
ylim([0,1.4])
set(gca,'YColor', [0 0 1], 'XColor', [0 0 1])
```

However, if anybody has a better idea, I would be very happy to explore it!

Thanks